# Несколько экземпляров одного и того же приложения Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sandbox

Как запустить несколько экземпляров одного и того же приложения? Допустим нужно запустить 3 разных скайпа, телеграма, стима и тд тп на Линуксе. В Windows я бы использовал простые песочницы... На Линукс я также нашёл песочницу FireJail, но она запускает только один экземпляр приложения и на последующий ругается, якобы он уже запущен (очень скудная документация, возможно я что-то упустил)

Какие есть еще способы решения моей проблемы?

Comment: Телеграм умеет запускать несколько экземпляров себя через опции -many и -workdir

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, название программ для примера... Это может быть всё что угодно, где можно сидеть с разных аккаунтов

Comment: Ну, не всё что угодно, а, скорее, то, что активно _не хочет_, чтобы вы в нём сидели с разных аккаунтов. Потому что если хочет, например, pidgin или тот же телеграм, то и вопрос не возникает.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, ну неужели нет таких инструментов в Linux, как песок в Windows для запуска нескольких экземпляров программ, я в это не верю

Comment: @Алексей, тот же firejail уже искал, где можно погладить?

Comment: a от другого пользователя пойдет?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, Да, запускает только один экземпляр приложения и на последующий ругается, якобы он уже запущен

Comment: Я не пробовал; по идее, если пользователь и xserver будет другой, то выйдет; переключаться между сеансами моментально ctrl+alt+F7,F8...

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov очевидно, нет необходимости запускать дополнительные иксы для вывода программ, запущенных от другого пользователя, равно как и на другой машине.

Comment: @Alexander Prokoshev, не настолько очевидно. Может какая-то программа через иксы определяет, что она вторая не нужна.

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov м-да. Firefox, например. Согласен.

Comment: @Sergei Kirjanov, какой день ищу решение... Запуск от других пользователей тоже уже пойдет

Comment: @Алексей, так с разными пользователями получилось?

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov, нет

Comment: @Алексей, и что конкретно не получается?